# Unbuntu 14.04 + Nginx + PHP5-FPM + sqlite3 : pdo sqlite could not find driver

Tags: ubuntu, php-fpm, php.ini, sqlite, pdo

`phpinfo()` says I have SQLite 3.x driver for PDO.

php.ini only mentions sqlite like so:

```
[sqlite]
; http://php.net/sqlite.assoc-case
;sqlite.assoc_case = 0

[sqlite3]
;sqlite3.extension_dir =
```

I tried running `sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite3` and it says: `E: Unable to locate package php5-sqlite3`

How do I enable sqlite?
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like just some package name confusion. I believe in both cases, you're attempting "sqlite3" instead of just "sqlite".

#### A: Have you installed sqlite3 on the server?

```
# Note the package on Ubuntu is "sqlite", not "sqlite3"
$ sudo apt-get install sqlite
```

#### B: The PHP package is `php5-sqlite`

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

#### Lastly

To search for available packages, you can use `apt-cache`:

```
$ apt-cache -n search php5-sqlite
> php5-sqlite - SQLite module for php5

$ apt-cache -n search sqlite
> ... other stuff ...
> sqlite - command line interface for SQLite
> sqlite-doc - SQLite documentation
> sqlite3-pcre - Perl-compatible regular expression support for SQLite
> sqlitebrowser - GUI editor for SQLite databases
> ... other stuff
```

Hope that helps!